# How to fill an inner gridview based on outer gridview selection (ASP.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested, objectdatasource

I have 2 GridViews, the InnerGridView is nested inside a TemplateField of my OuterGridView.
Each GridView has an ObjectDataSource (ODS). I want the InnerGridView to display data that is unique
to the GroupName that is listed in the OuterGridView. I have been Googling this for weeks,
seeing various ideas based around RowDataBound and the ODS Selecting event.

I don't think RowDataBound is the answer, because the Selecting event for the InnerGridView ODS
has already been called when RowDataBound is called for the OuterGridView.

So, I need to send a parameter to the ODS for the InnerGridView:

```
protected void ProductDataSource_Selecting( object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e ) {
        e.InputParameters["productGroup"] = <here I need to access the GroupName from the OuterGridView>;
}
```

Note: This method is assigned to the Selecting event of the InnerGridView ODS.

My question is: How do I access the GroupName from the OuterGridView... while I am processing the InnerGridView.
Here is an example of something that does not work: OuterGridView.SelectedRow.FindControl( "GroupName" ).ToString();

I have heard that one can find *any* control from inside the Selecting event by searching a certain hierarchy.
But I don't know how to access that hierarchy using the "e" or "sender" parms.
If I could find an explanation of the various objects and controls... and where they have a valid scope
and how they are accessed... that would be helpful.

Many thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

if you cast the sender object to a gridview object en then use the [SelectedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) like here and the get the groupname?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the Inner GridView with respect to GroupName of Outer GridView  do the following steps

1) if(!IsPostBack) Bind the Outer GridView.
2) In the Outer GridViews RowDataBound Event Find The Inner GridView by checking the condition
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       DataRowView drv = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem);
       GridView InnerGridView= (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("InnerGridView");
       if (InnerGridView!=null)
         {
              string GroupName = drv["GroupName"]; // to get the GropName. 
              InnerGridView.DataSource = "Query WRT the GroupName";
              InnerGridView.DataBind();
         }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully The Following Helps

ASPX page:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS1" runat="server"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="productGroup" 
        onrowdatabound="GV1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS2" runat="server">
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GV2" runat="server">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void GV1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         string productgroup = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["productGroup"].ToString();
         ObjectDataSource objDS = (ObjectDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("ODS2");
         objDS.SelectParameters["productGroup"].DefaultValue = productgroup;
      }

}
```

Note the use of a data key to hold the product group details.

Obviously you'll need to configure your object datasources and wire them up to the gridviews as needed.

This is adapted from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) outlining nesting gridviews using a SQL Datasource but the page life cycle should be the same.